# Controlling browser with IR remote

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm totally beginner at Raspberry Pi. Is there some way how to control web browser URL with infrared remote? I already saved key codes with LIRC library. (for example key volume up will open google.com, key volume down will open facebook.com etc.) 
How to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch a script that's waiting for IR and when you receive you code you launch a System command like this:

```
chromium-browser --kiosk www.google.com
```

hope it helpes